While loop filtering out user input using not if statements and indexes of lists
I am making a simple game with python on my own to test the little knowledge I have. Am trying to make a battleship style game, where users choose where they put their battleship and play against a computer, and am trying to filter the input of their response, have tried to make simple if x not in and/or statements to filter responses and the one I have found seems to be bad, just because it doesn't feel right, would appreciate some helpful criticism and help to see if I could do this part better. I am trying to get the user to input the position of where they want to put their battleship set in how the game coordinate 1a, 2a, 1b, 2b, etc... and then trying to filter out their response so it only allows the code block to continue past this if they enter correctly. I know I could set a long list with all the proper answers in a single list, but if I were to make this game like a 10 by 10 grid there'd be a hundred things, and I feel this is the most simple solution I can find, but I'd just like some helpful criticism.
def playerchoice():
    board_letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    board_nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    choice = [" ", " "]
    while choice[0] not in board_nums or choice[1] not in board_letters:
        print("Pick a place on the board for your ship between A1 and D4")
        choice = input().lower()
        choice = list(choice)
        if len(choice) < 2:
            choice.append("-")

    print(f"You have chosen {choice[0]}{choice[1]}")


    coorods = getplayership(choice)
    return coorods


Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the purpose of the code, rather than its mechanism.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  It's best to describe what value this code provides to its user.

helper predicate

tried to make simple if x not in ... and the one I have found seems to be bad

    while choice[0] not in board_nums or choice[1] not in board_letters:

I disagree.
The while condition you wrote seems perfectly sensible.
Feel free to keep it.
You might possibly wish to define a helper function,
def invalid(choice: str) -> bool:.
Then while invalid(choice): would read quite naturally.
string container
    choice = [" ", " "]
        ...
        choice = list(choice)

I understand why you might convert str to list while
you're learning and are still getting used to how things work.
But please realize that it's fine to keep choice as a string.
Even when it is a str, you can still access the [0]th
and the [1]st element with a square bracket dereference.
There's no need to convert to a list.
This is on the clunky side:
    print(f"You have chosen {choice[0]}{choice[1]}")

If you keep it as a string, then you can use the much more natural
    print(f"You have chosen {choice}")

sanitizing bad user input
        if len(choice) < 2:
            choice.append("-")

The intent here was to turn e.g. 4 into 4-
so the [1] dereference won't raise a KeyError.
But imagine the user simply hit the ENTER key,
giving us a zero-length string.
Might as well append "--" instead,
so we're guaranteed that both dereferences will succeed.
nit, typo: By coorods I suspect you meant coords,
short for "coordinates".

thank you, I guess I just figured there was a more scalable solution, but if you think this works then that's good to me. Also I did already know you could index a string, I don't know why my instinct was to turn it into a list, thank you for reminding me, had obv forgotten. And also yes good point about the zerolength string, hadn't thought of that. I haven't gotten around to or even heard of helper functions so I will have a look into that.

There's two big reasons for defining a Helper function. (1.) DRY up your code -- if you copy-n-pasted some code a couple times, turn each of those into a function call. (2.) Distinct concept -- if you feel the need to comment "# now we're doing A" and "# now we're doing B", that suggests you might wish to def a(): and def b():. For one thing it gives you a place to tack on a """docstring""" so you can describe A in as much detail as you feel is needed.

This is a bit more advanced, but here's a way you could scale the board up:
def validate(choice):
    
    #assuming only one letter
    letter = choice[0]
    
    #error handling needed in case user attempts to enter non-integer values
    try:
        number = int(choice[1:])
    except:
        return False
    
    #assuming 10x10 board. Letters go a-j, numbers 1-10
    if  ord(letter) < ord('a')  or \
        ord(letter) > ord('j')  or \
        number < 1         or \
        number > 10:
        return False
            

    return True

#test the function
print(validate('a3'))

If you haven't seen it before, the ord() function returns the ASCII value of the input character. Lowercase letters have consecutive ASCII values (ie. a is 97, b is 98 etc). So it suffices to check whether the ASCII value of your letter input is within a given range.
Edit: It will also suffice to directly compare the letter. ie. letter<'a' or letter>'j'
Thanks to @J_H for the correction.

It’s fine to compare one string to another, without using ord(). The result works out the same.

I like how this reads, obv it reads a little cleaner than my original one, but I do believe J_H is correct you could just compare "a" < "j" or "1" < "2" and those will eval correctly, I will keep this. I know this is a very simple program and function for this question but would there ever be a problem with someone putting a character in the function in the letter category that will eval between the letters? I assume where the memory is stored it's all in order and kept numerically, but is there ever a chance like a weird ascii character could sneak in and break it? Sorry I took long torespond

@Bobasarous Yep feel free to keep J_H's suggestion - I'll probably be using that in future code, too. I wouldn't recommend using straight string comparison for the numbers unless your board size will always be less than 10. That will cause you to run into problems where '11' is smaller than '2'. As for your other question, no, I don't believe that's possible. The ASCII mapping is exactly 1-1, so unless someone is intentionally trying to break your program with unicode characters or something weird, this should be safe.

Python has a < b < c notation so you could return 'a' <= letter <= 'j' and 1 <= number <= 10

There's also a String isnumeric() method. So len(choice) == 2 and choice[1].isnumeric() etc
